# How is the 'this' keyword parsed by the JS engine during the compilation phase?

Tags: javascript

```
function foo(bar) {
  this.name = bar;
}
```

During the compilation phase, when the JavaScript Engine is compiling the function `foo`, I understand that it registers `bar` in the scope of `foo`, but how is `this.name` parsed ? Given that the execution context that `this` points to  is determined by the call-site of the function, does this mean that `this` is not parsed at all **until** run-time ? I know that value assignment occurs  during run-time and we're assigning a value (`name`) on an object(`this`), so I'm assuming the line `this.name = bar` is not parsed at all from the perspective of scope resolution. Is this correct ?

Comment: JavaScript is an interpreted language, there's no notion of _before run-time_

Comment: It is [resolved at runtime](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-this-keyword)

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky - check [this](https://v8.dev/blog/background-compilation) out.

Comment: @RandyCasburn These are specifics of V8, not JavaScript.

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky JavaScript as a language still distinguishes between parsing and evaluation of code. And a *language* is never "interpreted" (or not), that's always the specifics of a particular implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's parsed at parse time, which you might also call compile time, but the distinction is tricky in modern optimised JITs. Either way, scope resolution is static, and the scopes involved in the expression `this.name` are resolved at the same time as the scope of `bar`.

The scope of the `this` keyword is the `function` (just like for the `bar` variable in your example), you can think of it as constant variable in the function scope, initialised from an invisible zeroth argument.

`.name` is not resolved at all since it's not a variable, it's a property name. The location in the target object will depend on the particular object; the property is looked up right when the assignment happens, when the function is called.

Answer (score 2):

"Parsing", "scope resolution", "compilation" (optimization, jit, or whatever, if at all), "run-time", can all be conceptualized as separate phases (which might be intertwined in the actual implementation).

In an actual implementation, the `this`-keyword-token is most likely parsed just like any other reserved keyword token during the parsing phase, nothing special about that.

The scope of the `this`-keyword can be determined statically, just like the scope of variables like `bar`. Consider this more interesting example to understand what it means:

```
var f = function(x) {
  var g = (y) => {
    this.name += x * y;
  }
  return g
}
```

In this example, we would know statically during the scope-analysis phase that:

- `this` is the receiver of `f` (which will be bound dynamically at the invocation site of `f`, i.e. we can know statically that it belongs to `f`, but we don't know until runtime what the receiver might be)
- `x` is a parameter of `f`
- `y` is a parameter of `g`
- `name` is just a statically known constant stringy-valued property name; It has no "scope" at all, you can think of it as a hard-coded constant `this['name'] = ...`.

The value that is used during the evaluation of `this` is bound at the call site at runtime, it's either the receiver if the function is called as a method, or a suitable global object / module if `f` is called as stand-alone function without a receiver.

Note that the specification does not *force* the interpreter to analyze anything statically: this is an implementation detail that is left to the one who implements the interpreter. A really sophisticated interpreter might decide to perform some escape analysis, and when it finds that, for example, some nested helper functions don't escape the scope of the enclosing function, it might try to compute the receivers ahead of time, or to inline the entire helper function at the call site.

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned three different stages of code processing: parsing, compilation, and runtime.

> During the compilation phase

Indeed, some interpreters may introduce compilation for optimization reasons, but this kind of compilation is not the same thing as compilation in Java or other compiled languages; e.g., you don't get to see compilation errors (an example of such error would be `number is not assignable to a string`). For this reason, JavaScript is thought of as an interpreted language, not compiled one.

> does this mean that `this` is not parsed at all **until** run-time ?

It is parsed, but not compiled. The expression `this.name = bar` is parsed as

```
<left-hand-operand> <binary-operation> <right-hand-operand>
```

… and evaluated at runtime as (roughly) "take the value of `bar` and put it to `this.name`". If this cannot be done for some reason (e.g., if `this` is nullish), there will be a runtime error.